# Error executing aapt: Return code 138

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have this error in my Android Project:

```
Error executing aapt: Return code 138
```

My menu resources look find and there is no error in my XML ( at least looks so).
How can I validate XML files?

Comment: It's a randomic error. Just delete the error and re run

Comment: @DerGolem It causes hundreds of "R Cannot be resolved", which deleting them is actually impossible

Comment: `R cannot be resolved` is normally caused by errors in xml files (ANY, not only layouts) or INVALID chars in file names (such as Upper Case letters). Try restarting Eclipse after a Project/Clean.

Comment: @DerGolem How can I find it? I have about 300 files!

Comment: By having much, much patience.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the problem was in a string I added to a menu title, but didn't add it to strings.xml!